# Is there a bug in the Advanced Find in MS CRM 2015 online, when in recursive queries? Example: Find Account Branches that belong to Account Branches

Tags: query-builder, dynamics-crm-2015

No matter what I have tried, I was unsuccessful in getting the Advanced Find feature of MS CRM 2015 online to show me *Active* Accounts that are of type **Branch** that have as their *parent* have an Account type again of **Branch**.

I have checked and re-checked the data but perhaps there is something wrong with my query in the Advanced Find feature.
Or there is a bug to it.

I have run this query in SQL as well, we have a BigData db that holds our CRM data and there it reveals the correct results (of course).

Here is my query so that you can see:

```
--BRANCH OF A BRANCH
select  [dbo].[fn_getDescFromCRMguid](a.[Parentaccountid]) as [ParentAccountName],
--[fn_getDescFromCRMguid] udf is just a look-up for descriptions and names
        (   select left(a3.[etf_accountlevel],6)
            from [Stg_CRMAccount] a3
            where a3.[accountid] = left(a.[parentaccountid],36)
        ) as [ParentAccountLevel],
        [dbo].[fn_getDescFromCRMguid](isnull(a.[owninguser], a.[owningteam])) as [OwningEntity],
        a.*
from [Stg_CRMAccount] a
where a.[statuscode] = 'Active::1'
and a.[etf_accountlevel] like 'Branch%'
and a.[Parentaccountid] is not null
and exists (
select 0
from [Stg_CRMAccount] a2
where a2.[statuscode] = 'Active::1'
and a2.[etf_accountlevel] like 'Branch%'
and left(a.[Parentaccountid],36) = a2.[accountid]
)
order by    a.[Parentaccountid],
            a.[name],
            a.[address1_city];
```

I am also attaching the screenshot of my Advanced Find query and please feel free to comment or let me know of any useful thoughts.

[image: Branch of a Branch MS CRM 2015 Advanced Find query]

I hope some person has any idea about this because to me it is puzzling.
I have navigated into the resulting Accounts from this and then into their parent Account and it was not a Branch.
Despite the clear (at least to me) specification of the Where clause under the use of the related Entity - Account, using the relation Parent Account.

The plot thickens even more, if you remove the Account Type = Branch for the related Entity and say change the Status = Active to Inactive then it will *very correctly* find and show only those Branches where their Parent is Inactive.

That leads me to suspect some kind of a recursive error with the query builder they are using.
It *finds* Account Type = Branch twice and erroneously does not differentiate between the first occurrence which is for the outer selection and the second occurrence which would be for the nested (in the Where clause) selection.

But all that is mere speculation.
I don't really know why it can't handle it.
It begs the question in what other scenarios it can mess up recursive query builds.

Your thoughts?

and here is my fetch XML from the Advanced Find query

```
<fetch version="1.0" output-format="xml-platform" mapping="logical" distinct="true">
  <entity name="account">
    <attribute name="etf_rating" />
    <attribute name="parentaccountid" />
    <attribute name="etf_lastcontact" />
    <attribute name="etf_city" />
    <attribute name="address1_line1" />
    <attribute name="etf_accountlevel" />
    <attribute name="name" />
    <attribute name="ownerid" />
    <attribute name="etf_segment" />
    <attribute name="accountid" />
    <order attribute="name" descending="false" />
    <filter type="and">
      <condition attribute="statecode" operator="eq" value="0" />
      <condition attribute="etf_accountlevel" operator="eq" value="964850002" />
    </filter>
    <link-entity name="account" from="parentaccountid" to="accountid" alias="ag">
      <filter type="and">
        <condition attribute="statecode" operator="eq" value="0" />
        <condition attribute="etf_accountlevel" operator="eq" value="964850002" />
      </filter>
    </link-entity>
  </entity>
</fetch>
```

Comment: Just a thought, could you export that fetchxml and run it in a console app that you connect to your CRM.

Comment: I hadn't thought of that. I will try that and see what happens..